# Group sharing lock for sharing recalculation or CRUD of a record

Tags: sharing

I was reading this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/01/salesforce-group-membership-sharing-for-peak-performance.html). It mentions when the group sharing locks are held, all other group membership operations must wait for the lock.
Is this applicable to Sharing Recalculation operations or CRUD of the record or both
If CRUD  of the record is applicable, does it mean, users belong to the same group membership can update the same record at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The lock is referring to an administrative lock on sharing. For example, a substantial modification to the role hierarchy can prohibit changes to sharing rules until it completes. This lock has nothing to do with CRUD operations on the record itself.

Each record is locked when a user edits a record, and this is done at the transaction level. This means that only one user can modify a record in a single transaction at a time. This rule is in place to prevent accidental overwrites.

When more than one transaction attempts to lock a record, the second transaction will wait a little bit to try and acquire the lock. If this lock wait times out, the user will receive an error telling them to try again later.

Comment: In the following scenario: If administrator is to move a user from one role to another (assume that particular user holds large amount of data in CustomObject__c), and Salesforce require 10 seconds to perform modification/changes under the hood. During this 10 seconds, if another user save any of the CustomObject__c's record, can I assume the user might get "UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW" error?

Comment: @WenHao no, the sharing table lock won't affect the ability for records to be edited.